# How to fix Cannot find libcocos2dcpp.so when trying to support 64 bit

Tags: c++, android-studio, cocos2d-x

i have a cocos2dx game in android studio and when I'm trying to make it support 64 bit requirement then i got this error "couldn't find "libcocos2dcpp.so" " when i start project on my phone

what I've done to support the 64 bit : 
i searched on cocos2dx forum for solution to support 64 bit and i found a solution :
* i've Modified Application.MK file : adding APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a
* gradle.properties : adding PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a:arm64-v8a
* build.gradle  : adding ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxxxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xxxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xxxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xxxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.xxxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xxx.kidslearngame-oq27wbETBHeT2MFhWg9cOw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libcocos2dcpp.so"
```

those are the solution that i found but when i run the app on my phone it's crashing and giving me the error above but when i removed  ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a' from gradle.build it's working good but when i upload it to play store they show me the warning message  "your app those not support the 64 bit requirement "

Comment: can any one help me with this issue /*?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should clear the project and in Android Studio select in the menu File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Below I give the settings that work for me:

In Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a
```

In gradle.properties

```
PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a:arm64-v8a
```

In app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion PROP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION.toInteger()
    buildToolsVersion PROP_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    def versionMajor = 0
    def versionMinor = 9
    def versionPatch = 0
    def versionBuild = 0

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "YOUR APP ID"
        minSdkVersion PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        // versionCode 1
        // versionName "1.0"
        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"

        externalNativeBuild {
            if (PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'ndk-build') {
                ndkBuild {
                    targets 'MyGame'
                    arguments 'NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang'
                    arguments '-j' + Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
                }
            }
            else if (PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'cmake') {
                cmake {
                    targets 'MyGame'
                    arguments "-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", \
                              "-DUSE_CHIPMUNK=TRUE", "-DUSE_BULLET=TRUE"
                    cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
                    // prebuilt root must be defined as a directory which you have right to access or create if you use prebuilt
                    // set "-DGEN_COCOS_PREBUILT=ON" and "-DUSE_COCOS_PREBUILT=OFF" to generate prebuilt,  this way build cocos2d-x libs
                    // set "-DGEN_COCOS_PREBUILT=OFF" and "-DUSE_COCOS_PREBUILT=ON" to use prebuilt, this way not build cocos2d-x libs
                    //arguments "-DCOCOS_PREBUILT_ROOT=/Users/laptop/cocos-prebuilt"
                    //arguments "-DGEN_COCOS_PREBUILT=OFF", "-DUSE_COCOS_PREBUILT=OFF"
                }
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters = []
            abiFilters.addAll(PROP_APP_ABI.split(':').collect{it as String})
        }
    }

    splits {
        // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
        abi {
            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable true
            //enable gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(":app:assembleRelease")
            //enable project.hasProperty('splitApks')

            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.
            reset()

            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"

            // Specifies that we want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk true
        }
    }

    // Map for the version code that gives each ABI a value.
    def abiCodes = ['x86':3, 'x86_64':4, 'armeabi-v7a':1, 'arm64-v8a':2]

    // APKs for the same app that all have the same version information.
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        // Assigns a different version code for each output APK.
        variant.outputs.each {
            output ->
                def abiName = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                output.versionCodeOverride = abiCodes.get(abiName, 0) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
```

I hope this helps.